# ¿Como puedo eliminar un elemento en especifico de un json en un LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, web

Tengo una lista de cosas para hacer en una webpage que se almacenan en el local Storage
para eliminar un elemento lo que hago es eliminar el ultimo que se agrego pero quiero poder seleccionar el que se va a eliminar
Funcion con la que agrego elementos

```
let itemsLista = localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : [];

itemsLista.forEach(agregarHab);
function agregarHab(texto){
    if(texto!=''){
        const li = document.createElement('li')
        li.textContent='✦ '+texto;
        LIST.appendChild(li);
        msgERROR.style.display='none'

    }
    else{
        msgERROR.style.display='block'
    }
}
function newHab(){
    itemsLista.push(INPUTLISTA.value);
    localStorage.setItem('items',JSON.stringify(itemsLista));
    agregarHab(INPUTLISTA.value);
    INPUTLISTA.value='';
}
```

Función con la que elimino elementos

```
function eliminar(){
    localStorage.removeItem('items')
    INPUTLISTA.innerHTML ='';
    itemsLista = [];
    LIST.removeChild(LIST.firstChild);
}
```

para acceder al proyecto completo : https://github.com/MrChrisFabian/FinalProject_ppy.git